# Не резолвятся доменные имена через прокси

Tags: qt, безопасность, proxy, dns, qtwebengine

Делаю браузер на Qt с использованием QtWebEngine. Когда прикручиваю на него прокси, возникает утечка dns.

`QWebEngineSettings::DnsPrefetchEnabled` не работает.

Пробовал с помощью `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` ловить эти запросы, тоже не помогло.

Например:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEnginePage>
#include <QWebEngineProfile>
#include <QWebEngineSettings>
#include <QNetworkProxy>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    QNetworkProxy proxy;

    proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);

    proxy.setHostName("proxy_host");
    proxy.setPort(proxy_port);
    proxy.setCapabilities(QNetworkProxy::HostNameLookupCapability);
    //proxy.setUser(user);
    //proxy.setPassword(pass);

    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);

    QWebEngineProfile *profile = QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile();

    QWebEngineSettings* sett = profile->settings();
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::XSSAuditingEnabled, false);
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
    sett->setUnknownUrlSchemePolicy(QWebEngineSettings::AllowAllUnknownUrlSchemes);
    sett->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::DnsPrefetchEnabled, false);

    profile->setUseForGlobalCertificateVerification();

    QWebEngineView *w = new QWebEngineView(this);
    QWebEnginePage *p = new QWebEnginePage(profile,this);
    w->setPage(p);
    w->load(QUrl("https://browserleaks.com/ip"));

    this->setCentralWidget(w);
    this->resize(900,900);

}
```

Comment: приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, сделано

Answer (score 0):

Написал локальный прокси сервер и с помощью флага `--host-resolver-rules`(в 5.15 он наконец начал работать) ссылал все на него.Задача в целом решена, но если вы знаете более элегантные решения, милости прошу к моему шалашу.